# I need someone who can write Java Streams. I want to write this code as a Java stream type

Tags: java, list, java-stream

```
public List testList(List numberList) {
  List realList = new ArrayList();
  for (Iterator iterator = numberList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String num = (String) iterator.next();
    realList.add(call(num));
  }
  return realList;
}
```

I want to write this code as a Java stream type.

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think you nead that:

```
 numberList.stream()
            .map(arg-> arg.toString())
            .map(arg -> call(arg))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public List testList(List numberList) {
  return numberList.stream()
      .map(s -> call((String) s))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```